How do you scale a polygon by X, Y values in ArcGIS Pro?
I am working with a shapefile that has a series of polygons (for states, countries, etc.)
In my case, I would like apply a linear transformation to one of the polygons using this matrix:









0.64
0


0
1.0



In other words, I would like each X value to be multiplied by .64 and each y value by 1 (effectively leaving it unchanged).
In ArcGIS Pro, when I select the polygon, enter the edit mode, and select scale, it only allows me to change its size altering both X and Y values (like resizing a picture). Is there any way that I can scale by just this specific X value instead?
Edit: I am guessing that this cannot be accomplished using the scale tool, but instead requires performing an affine transformation using the transform tool. Are there any small examples of how I would accomplish this?

Scaling is done relative to an origin. If the origin is at 0,0 then it's just multiplication, otherwise you have to subtract the origin, multiply, and add the origin back in. Expecting a tool to do this for you seems iffy. I'd just write a filter using a DA SearchCursor nested within an InsertCursor to populate a new feature class, adjusting the Geometry coords on the fly

Can you elaborate on what you really want? If you genuinely want to multiply  the value of each X coordinate of each vertex by 0.64 then this is a simple translation of the polygon in a horizontal direction to the west, with every vertex moved in that sense. However, if you want to "squash" the polygon in the x direction and maintain the centroid then the nodes to the west of the centroid would be increased in x values and those to the east would be decreased.

Create extent polygon of the one of interest. Modify it accordingly and use spatial adjustment tool. Inputs:

Output (scaling around centroid):

Note: I cut original polygon and moved it to existing centroid. If you cut extent on one side and choose not to move it, third displacement link goes from old centroid to a new one
